# How to get Opening and Closing stock using RIA Service

Tags: c#, linq, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-lightswitch

I want to get my item's opening and closing stock data day wise by using Linq RIA Service in LightSwitch application.

My requirement is

Input Data Format

**ItemLocation (Entity)**

```
Item     Location        Quantity    Modified Date
Item A   Location A      0           Date
Item A   Location B      0           Date
```

From Receipt (PurchaseOrder) entity, item quantities will add to ItemLocation entity.
From Consumption & Wastage entities item quantities will deduct from ItemLocation entity.
The ClosingBalance must be ((OpeningBalance + Receipt) - (Consumption + Wastage)).
And the closing balance must be carry to next day opening balance.

**Item A**

Expected Output Data Format

```
Date            OpeningBalance      Receipt     Consumption   Wastage      ClosingBalance
27/03/2014      0                   100         50            5                 45
28/03/2014      45                  15          30            4                 26
..................................so on up to current date.
```

My schema design is as follows

```
Item (Id, ItemName)

ItemLocation (Id, LocationName, Quantity)

PurchaseOrder (Receipt)

Production (Consumption) (ConsumptionQuantity & WastageQuantity)
```

- Relationship between Item and ItemLocation is one to many.
- Relationship between Item and PurchaseOrder is one to many.
- Relationship between Item and Production is one to many.

Kindly anybody provide me any linq sample query to get this data by using WCF Ria Service in LS Silverlight.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Pay for me, will develop your requirement. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please send me your email address...